# angular ngTableParams from json

Tags: json, angularjs, django, ngtable

Having problem with creating table from json data.

Using Django + AngularJS

Data is not displayed.

`tables.js`

```
app.controller('tableCtrl', function(ngTableParams, tableData) {
    var data = tableData
    this.tableLatestContests = new ngTableParams({
        page: 1,
        count: 5,
    }, {
        total: data.length,
        getData: function($defer, params) {
            $defer.resolve(data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count())); 
        }
    }
});
```

`services.js`

```
app.service('tableData', [$resource, function($resource) {
    this.data = $resouce('data/table.json', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
        }
    }
});
```

`data/table.json`

```
[
    {"id": 1, "market": "name", "uid": "uid"},
    {"id": 2, "market": "name2", "uid": "uid2"},
]
```

`table.html` (on app changed `{{` & `}}` to `//` & `//` because of django syntax)

```
<div class="card-body card-padding" data-ng-controller="tableCtrl as tctrl">
    <table ng-table="tctrl.tableLastestContests" class="table table-striped table-vmiddle">
        <tr ng-repeat="w in $data">
            <td data-title="'ID'"> // w.id // </td>
            <td data-title="'MARKET'"> // w.market // </td>
            <td data-title="'UID'"> // w.uid // </td>
        </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
```

Any ideas how to read and display table with tada from json ?

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding something. $resource creates instance of service instead of getting data from the service. This is why you have service which is capable of getting data form json instead of data form json.

```
this.srv = $resouce('data/table.json', {}, {
    query: {
        method: 'GET',
        isArray: true,
    }
}
this.data = this.srv.query();
```

After successful loading you will get data in `this.data`.

Of course you can change last line to something like this:

```
var _self = this;
this.srv.query(function(response) {
    _self.data = response;
});
```

In case you do not want to create service, you can do:

```
$http.get('data/table.json').then(function(response) {
    _self.data = response.data;
});
```

My post does not include support for errors.

You can read more here:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Also, you have error in view. Use `data` instead of `$data` in `ng-repeat`.

Comment: Both are not working.

On `$http.get()` i see that request goes, but data still not displayed.

Comment: Still not working. When making `$http` request and function `.then` not adding data to variable.